np.where() when creating a new column
I'm trying to create a new "New" column in the Data Frame based on the existing ones:

if the "Min date" column is null, then we take the data from the "Start Date" column,
otherwise we take the date from the "Min date" in string format, concatenate it with the time from the "Time" column.

We format the result in the date-time.
fffg = pd.DataFrame({'N': [1, 2, 3], 'MinDate': [date(2023,1,2), None, date(2022,1,7)], 
              'Time': [datetime.time(8, 48, 0), datetime.time(8, 48, 0), datetime.time(8, 48, 0)], 
              'Start_Date': [datetime.datetime(2022,4,1,15,10), datetime.datetime(2023,4,1,15,10), datetime.datetime(2022,5,1,15,10)]})
fffg['MinDate'] = pd.to_datetime(fffg['MinDate'])
fffg['New'] = np.where(pd.notnull(fffg['MinDate']),  
                       pd.to_datetime(fffg['MinDate'].astype(str)+' '+fffg['Time'].astype(str)),
                       fffg['Start_Date']
                       )                       
fffg

But I get an error:
ValueError: time data "NaT 08:48:00" doesn't match format "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", at position 1. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.

It seems as if filtering inside np.where() is being ignored. How can this mistake be avoided?

pd.to_datetime(fffg['MinDate'].astype(str)+' '+fffg['Time'].astype(str)) is using the value which is Null and tehrefore cannot perform the action. didn't you want to use Start_Date here?

I corrected the code in the question, but the error is the same

You have to avoid performing your conversion on empty values and therefore need to handle the conditions separately, therefore only attempting the conversion if MinDate is not null.
Example:
# Convert MinDate and Start_Date columns to datetime
fffg['MinDate'] = pd.to_datetime(fffg['MinDate'])
fffg['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(fffg['Start_Date'])

# Create 'New' column based on the condition
fffg['New'] = np.where(
    pd.notnull(fffg['MinDate']),
    pd.to_datetime(fffg['MinDate'].dt.strftime(
        '%Y-%m-%d') + ' ' + fffg['Time'].astype(str)),
    fffg['Start_Date']
)

fffg


After converting MinTime to datetime column,
fffg['MinDate'] = pd.to_datetime(fffg['MinDate'])

missing values are filled with NaT values.
The attempt to parse the concatenated MinTime to Time columns fails because pd.to_datetime cannot parse NaT <time> values.
You can arrange the operations so that the data format of the resulting series passed to pd.to_datetime is similar by converting 'Start_Date' to str type and  applying pd.to_datetime last.
mask = fffg['MinDate'].isna()

fffg['New'] = pd.to_datetime(
    np.where(
        mask, 
        fffg['Start_Date'].astype(str), 
        fffg['MinDate'].astype(str).str.cat(fffg['Time'].astype(str), sep=' ')
    )
)

